The Time Traveler's Other Wife
You know the story, The Time Traveler's Wife, correct?
I read a short story in Analog many years prior to the publication of TTTW about a time traveler who started at the end of his wife's life and went backward in time to the beginning of her life.
He is young when he meets his wife for the first time and she is old and knows who he is. He reads his journal about their life together. He finds out that he will be pulled out of time, each time and land at a moment earlier along the timeline, when he is older by his own measurement, but his wife is younger.
Eventually, he lands in his wife's earliest days as an old man.
Anyone know this story?

Possibly a duplicate of this question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/262899/short-story-with-character-living-life-in-non-sequential-segments
